# Robotics SLAM datasets - scaling factor

Tags: slam

There are several robotics datasets for SLAM, like [this one](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/file_formats).

In this webpage you can see that the depth image is scaled by a factor of 5000, so that float depth images can be stored in 16 bit png files:

```
The depth images are scaled by a factor of 5000, i.e., a pixel value of 5000
in the depth image corresponds to a distance of 1 meter from the camera, 10000
to 2 meter distance, etc. A pixel value of 0 means missing value/no data.
```

I do not understand why this value is chosen. Why not simply 1000, so that there is a conversion of meters to millimeters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG does not support float numbers (afaik). Hence the depth value needs to be encoded as a fixed point value. The fixed point was chosen, I guess, to get a good trade-off between accuracy (0.2 mm) and range (13 m).

Comment: Exactly, instead of saving a float depth image in a xml or yml (ascii), this scaling is used in order to use png files as you say. But can you give a reference for the values that you mention for accuracy/range? Are they just a rule of thumb for robotics, or do you have a specific reference?

Comment: Rule of thumb, and not universal in robotics. I would say mostly depends on the range of your depth sensor. My guess: they wanted to have a range of 10 m, and then rounded for the step size.